# Clipping a catalog with lasclipCircle returns "no point found within region of interest"

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, clip, lidar, lidr

I'm trying to clip a catalog using lidR (v2.0.1) package. I've tried with `lasclipCircle` and `lasclip`. It gives me the error: no point in ROI, but when I'm viewing the shapefile using `mapview` (I've exported the X and Y coordinates from this shapefile) and the catalog, they are at the same place.

Here's my code.

```
page1 <- catalog("O:/LiDAR/NB_LiDAR_16/page1")
Buffer_16 <- readOGR(dsn = "O:/2018_Regen/Derived GIS", layer = "Buffer_16")
X_16 <- Buffer_16@data[["DDLONG"]]
Y_16 <- Buffer_16@data[["DDLAT"]]
page1_points <- lasclipCircle(page1, xcenter = X_16,ycenter = Y_16, radius = 10)
```

or

```
page1_points <- lasclip(page1, Buffer_16)
```

I get the following error:

> Error : No point found for within region of interest 2.

I got the same message for ROI 1 and all the other ROI as well.

Summary of `Buffer_16`

```
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
      min     max
x 2457220 2613228
y 7490508 7662516
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+init=epsg:2953 +proj=sterea +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=-66.5 +k=0.999912 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=7500000 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs]
Data attributes:
    OBJECTID         MAPNO         PLOTID          X             Y           DDLAT           DDLONG       SCHEDULE
 Min.   : 62.0   4721   : 11   23239  :  1   2541224: 11   7600512:  9   Min.   :46.41   Min.   :-67.07   1:179   
 1st Qu.:257.5   4921   : 11   26157  :  1   2539224: 10   7554512:  8   1st Qu.:47.09   1st Qu.:-66.46           
 Median :454.0   5230   : 10   26159  :  1   2543224:  9   7604512:  8   Median :47.35   Median :-66.14           
 Mean   :415.1   4425   :  9   26160  :  1   2505224:  8   7646512:  8   Mean   :47.34   Mean   :-66.12           
 3rd Qu.:578.5   4714   :  9   26369  :  1   2501224:  7   7602512:  7   3rd Qu.:47.61   3rd Qu.:-65.88           
 Max.   :790.0   5523   :  9   26370  :  1   2507224:  7   7648512:  7   Max.   :47.96   Max.   :-65.00           
                 (Other):120   (Other):173   (Other):127   (Other):132                                            
 ISPSP     OBJECTID_1   objectid_2 PHOTO_YEAR  LABEL     NUMBERING   Shape_Leng       Shape_Area       
 0:131   Min.   :5    Min.   :2    2016:179   2016:179   0:179     Min.   :749732   Min.   :1.876e+10  
 1: 48   1st Qu.:5    1st Qu.:2                                    1st Qu.:749732   1st Qu.:1.876e+10  
         Median :5    Median :2                                    Median :749732   Median :1.876e+10  
         Mean   :5    Mean   :2                                    Mean   :749732   Mean   :1.876e+10  
         3rd Qu.:5    3rd Qu.:2                                    3rd Qu.:749732   3rd Qu.:1.876e+10  
         Max.   :5    Max.   :2                                    Max.   :749732   Max.   :1.876e+10`
```

Summary of `page1`:

```
class       : LAScatalog
extent      : 2457000 , 2590000 , 7542000 , 7647000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:2953 +proj=sterea +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=-66.5 +k=0.999912 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=7500000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
area        : 43 km²
points      : 844.56 million points
density     : 19.6 points/m²
num. files  : 43 
Summary of the processing options:
  - Catalog will be processed by file respecting the original tiling pattern
  - Catalog will be processed using 1 core(s).
Summary of the output options:
  - Outputs will be returned in R objects.
Summary of the input options:
  - readLAS will be called with the following select option: * 
  - readLAS will be called with the following filter option:    `
```

Comment: Could you please confirm that all of your data are in the same projected coordinate system?

Comment: Please provide more details e.g. a summary of `Buffer_16` and a summary of `page1`. Aaron is right but it may also be because the region of interest 2 (plot 2) belongs in a region with no data (data removed by the provider or any other reason). Plot number 1 (at least) has been extracted so coordinates seem to match

Comment: Btw, the message should not be an error, not even a warning. It should only be a message to highlight the fact that you've extracted a 0 points region.

Comment: JRR: I got the same message for ROI 1 and all the other ROI.                                   Here's the projected coordinate system of Buffer_16 : [+proj=sterea +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=-66.5 +k=0.999912 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=7500000 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs]                                                                                                               And for page1:  +init=epsg:2953 +proj=sterea +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=-66.5 +k=0.999912 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=7500000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: Please show us a summary of your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing that:

```
X_16 <- Buffer_16@data[["DDLONG"]]
Y_16 <- Buffer_16@data[["DDLAT"]]
page1_points <- lasclipCircle(page1, xcenter = X_16,ycenter = Y_16, radius = 10)
```

you are trying to extract long/lat coordinates from projected coordinates. So basically you tried to extract a disc at (47, -66) from data at (2457000, 7490000). *No data* is the expected behavior. You must recompute `DDLONG` `DDLAT` in the good coordinate system. Maybe the attributes `X` and `Y` of your shapefile are what you actually need. But in your data they are factors that must be converted to numbers first.

```
X_16 <- as.numeric(as.character(Buffer_16@data[["X"]]))
Y_16 <- as.numeric(as.character(Buffer_16@data[["Y"]]))
page1_points <- lasclipCircle(page1, X_16, Y_16, 10)
```

If many of your coordinates don't actually belong into your tiles you will extract many empty point clouds. In this case filter the empty ones

```
not.empty <- Filter(Negate(is.empty), page1_points)
```